# Fix for dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I'm trying to fix two warnings when compiling a specific program using GCC.  The warnings are:

**warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break
strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]**

and the two culprits are:

```
unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*((unsigned int*)dcc->incoming_buf));
```

and

```
*((unsigned int*)dcc->outgoing_buf) = htonl (dcc->file_confirm_offset);
```

**incoming_buf** and **outgoing_buf** are defined as follows:

```
char                    incoming_buf[LIBIRC_DCC_BUFFER_SIZE];

char                    outgoing_buf[LIBIRC_DCC_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

This seems subtly different than the other examples of that warning I've been examining.  I would prefer to fix the problem rather than disable strict-aliasing checks.

There have been many suggestions to use a union - what might be a suitable union for this case?

Comment: Interesting... strict-aliasing shouldn't apply to `char*`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, what you are missing is there is no aliasing violation when an object of type `T1` is accessed with a lvalue of type `T2` and `T2` is `char`, but when `T1` is `char` and `T2` is not of a signed/unsigned variant of `char`, there is an aliasing violation.

Comment: @Mysticial: You got it the wrong way round!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First off, let's examine why you get the aliasing violation warnings.

**Aliasing rules** simply say that you can only access an object through its own type, its signed / unsigned variant type, or through a character type (`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`).

C says violating aliasing rules invokes undefined behavior (*so don't!*).

In this line of your program:

```
unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*((unsigned int*)dcc->incoming_buf));
```

although the elements of the `incoming_buf` array are of type `char`, you are accessing them as `unsigned int`. Indeed the result of the dereference operator in the expression `*((unsigned int*)dcc->incoming_buf)` is of `unsigned int` type.

This is a violation of the aliasing rules, because you only have the right to access elements of `incoming_buf` array through (see rules summary above!) `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

Notice you have exactly the same aliasing issue in your second culprit:

```
*((unsigned int*)dcc->outgoing_buf) = htonl (dcc->file_confirm_offset);
```

You access the `char` elements of `outgoing_buf` through `unsigned int`, so it's an aliasing violation.

**Proposed solution**

To fix your issue, you could try to have the elements of your arrays directly defined in the type you want to access:

```
unsigned int incoming_buf[LIBIRC_DCC_BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof (unsigned int)];
unsigned int outgoing_buf[LIBIRC_DCC_BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof (unsigned int)];
```

(By the way the width of `unsigned int` is implementation defined, so you should consider using `uint32_t` if your program assumes `unsigned int` is 32-bit).

This way you could store `unsigned int` objects in your array without violating the aliasing rules by accessing the element through the type `char`, like this:

```
*((char *) outgoing_buf) =  expr_of_type_char;
```

or

```
char_lvalue = *((char *) incoming_buf);
```

---

**EDIT:**

I've entirely reworked my answer, in particular I explain why the program gets the aliasing warnings from the compiler.

Comment: the warning can silenced by double casting through `void *`. see my answer

Answer (score 35):

To fix the problem, *don't pun and alias*! The only "correct" way to read a type `T` is to allocate a type `T` and populate its representation if needed:

```
uint32_t n;
memcpy(&n, dcc->incoming_buf, 4);
```

In short: If you want an integer, you need to make an integer. There's no way to cheat around that in a language-condoned way.

The only pointer conversion which you are allowed (for purposes of I/O, generally) is to treat the address of *an existing variable* of type `T` as a `char*`, or rather, as the pointer to the first element of an array of chars of size `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: I'm not sure `sizeof(uint32_t)` is guaranteed to be 4, so you may need to adjust your `memcpy`

Comment: @OmarL: correct. `uint32_t` is guaranteed to have exactly 32 value bits and no padding bits, but `sizeof(uint32_t)` can be `2` if `unsigned char` has 16 bits and even `1` if `unsigned char` has 32 bits. The example should be amended as `memcpy(&n, dcc->incoming_buf, sizeof(n));`

Answer (score 6):

```
union
{
    const unsigned int * int_val_p;
    const char* buf;
} xyz;

xyz.buf = dcc->incoming_buf;
unsigned int received_size = ntohl(*(xyz.int_val_p));
```

Simplified explanation
1. c++ standard states that you should attempt to align data yourself, g++ goes an extra mile to generate warnings on the subject.
2. you should only attempt it if you completely understand the data alignment on your architecture/system and inside your code (for example the code above is a sure thing on Intel 32/64 ; alignment 1; Win/Linux/Bsd/Mac)
3. the only practical reason to use the code above is to avoid compiler warnings , WHEN and IF you know what you are doing

Answer (score 3):

If I may, IMHO, for this case, the problem is the design of the ntohl and htonl and related function APIs. They should not have been written as numeric argument with numeric return. (and yes, I understand the macro optimization point)
They should have been designed as the 'n' side being a pointer to a buffer. When this is done, the whole problem goes away and the routine is accurate whichever endian the host is.
For example (with no attempt to optimize):

```
inline void safe_htonl(unsigned char *netside, unsigned long value) {
    netside[3] = value & 0xFF;
    netside[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    netside[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    netside[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
};
```

Comment: If the Standard were to include a standard set of big-endian and little-endian "fetch" and "stuff" routines, such routines could usefully have behavior defined in terms of octets even on machines where `CHAR_BIT` isn't eight, thus enhancing the portability of networking code on such machines.

Answer (score 2):

If you have reasons that do not allow you to change type of source object (like it was in my case), and you are absolutely confident that the code is correct and it does what intended to do with that char array, to avoid warnings you may do the following:

```
unsigned int* buf = (unsigned int*)dcc->incoming_buf;
unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*buf);
```

Comment: Casting away warnings is bad.  This code does nothing about violating strict aliasing and can also violate alignment restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded a project from GCC 6 to GCC 9, and started seeing this warning. The project is on a 32-bit microcontroller, and I had created a struct to access the individual bytes of a 32-bit machine register:

```
struct TCC_WEXCTRL_t
{
    byte    OTMX;
    byte    DTIEN;
    byte    DTLS;
    byte    DTHS;
};
```

and then coded:

```
((TCC_WEXCTRL_t *)&TCC0->WEXCTRL)->DTLS = PwmLoDeadTime;
```

which produced the warning in the new compiler. I found I could eliminate the warning by combining my struct in a union with the original type:

```
union TCC_WEXCTRL_t
{
    TCC_WEXCTRL_Type std;
    struct  
    {
        byte    OTMX;
        byte    DTIEN;
        byte    DTLS;
        byte    DTHS;
    };    
};
```

where `TCC_WEXCTRL_Type` is the type of the `WEXCTRL` member as provided in the manufacturer's header files.

I'm not sure if this is considered a fully compliant fix, or if GCC is just failing to catch it. If this hadn't worked (or gets caught in another GCC upgrade), I would move on to using a union of the pointer types, as described on this thread by Real Name.

Answer (score -1):

**If** you are certain you know what you are doing, do this:

```
void *tmp = dcc->incoming_buf;
unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*((unsigned int*) tmp));
```

or just:

```
unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*((unsigned int*) ((void *) dcc->incoming_buf)));
```

Comment: I'm finding that the `g++` compiler with args `std=c++11` and `-Wall` is still producing this warning for me even when double casting via `(void*)`. Honestly if the compiler maintainers persist in telling people off for taking advantage of byte-level optimisations that make lower level languages like C attractive in the first place, they're really just degrading the value of using languages like C in the first place. Another solution is to not use `-Wall` ;)

Answer (score -3):

Cast pointer to unsigned and then back to pointer.

unsigned int received_size = ntohl (*((unsigned *)((unsigned) dcc->incoming_buf)) );