# Dereferencing type-punned pointer breaks strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c, pointers, casting, gcc-warning

Following error shows while compilation process:

```
ccm.c:152:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
      HWREG(AES_AES_IV_0) = ((uint32_t *)&ui8A0)[0];

ccm.c:325:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict- aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
      ((uint32_t  *)&ui8MIC)[0] = HWREG(AES_AES_TAG_OUT_0);
```

Line 152-155:

```
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_0) = ((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[0];
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_1) = ((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[1];
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_2) = ((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[2];
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_3) = ((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[3];
```

`ui8A0` is 16-sized **uint8_t** array:

```
uint8_t  ui8A0[16];
```

Line 325-328:

```
((uint32_t  *)&ui8MIC)[0] = HWREG(AES_AES_TAG_OUT_0);
((uint32_t  *)&ui8MIC)[1] = HWREG(AES_AES_TAG_OUT_1);
((uint32_t  *)&ui8MIC)[2] = HWREG(AES_AES_TAG_OUT_2);
((uint32_t  *)&ui8MIC)[3] = HWREG(AES_AES_TAG_OUT_3);
```

`ui8MIC` is 16-sized **uint8_t** array:

```
uint8_t volatile ui8MIC[16];
```

HWREG macro looks like this:

```
#define HWREG(x)                                                              \
        (*((volatile uint32_t *)(x)))
```

That's how I understand it: 
`ui8A0` is an array, `&ui8A0` is an address of first element, `(uint32_t  *)&ui8A0` is an address for array where elements are uint32_t contrary to uint8_t which were before, `((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[0]` is the value of first element of an array which elements are uint32_t.

So basically this code has to pass 4 elements of `ui8A0` to `HWREG` macro.

It looks like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1625856
But I would prefer not to use the union-based solution.

Is there any other, easier way to handle it?

My only idea is to replace:

```
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_1) = ((uint32_t  *)&ui8A0)[1];
```

with:

```
HWREG(AES_AES_IV_1) = (uintptr_t)&ui8A0[4];
```

Comment: *"Is there any other, easier way to handle it?"* - `memcpy` to a temporary, and then assign the value. You may be able to `memcpy` without the temporary, but I did not dive deep into the code. Also see @KerrekSB's answer at [Fix for dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825251/608639). You might also be able to use inline ASM because ASM does not suffer C rules. If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be easier to test things for you.